# The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it

Tags: c#

Ok, my current code is work in progress and probably I will try to do the same thing with the Async CTP. But I will still like to understand whats happening.

I have a function like below

```
// In MainWindow.xaml.cs
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => helper.Send());

// In class HttpHelper
public void Send()
{
    // ...

    try
    {
        Status = Statuses.Uploading;
        // write to request stream

        Status = Statuses.Downloading;
        // write to response stream

        Status = Statuses.Idle; // the exception is thrown here
        // ...
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Full Code for `HttpHelper` **[@pastebin](http://pastebin.com/cMdXpFdx)**. `Send()` on line 76

I wonder why I get the exception? Maybe I did something wrong with the threading, but why is the exception raised only after I successfully set the `Status` property 2 times?

## UPDATE: The Cause ...

I had an event handler, listening to the `StatusChanged` event, in 1 if clause, I forgot to use the UI thread to update the UI

```
helper.StatusChanged += (s, evt) =>
{
    _dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => txtStatus.Text = helper.Status.ToString())); // I used _dispatcher here correctly

    if (helper.Status == HttpHelper.Statuses.Idle || helper.Status == HttpHelper.Statuses.Error)
       progBar.IsIndeterminate = false; // but not here
};
```

Comment: because sometimes you get the UI thread and sometimes you don't....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update**: I missed the (in my defense, small) comment in your code that gave away that you're using WPF/Silverlight and not Windows Forms.

Still, looks like you were able to take the basic gist of what I said and apply it to your own scenario properly (using `Dispatcher.Invoke` rather than `Control.Invoke`)—well done ;)

---

I'm guessing an event handler attached to your `StatusChanged` event updates a `StatusLabel` control on your UI? If that's the case, then you need to `Invoke` that call from the UI thread; e.g.:

```
void HttpHelper_StatusChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var httpHelper = (HttpHelper)sender;
    UpdateStatus(httpHelper.Status);
}

void UpdateStatus(HttpHelper.Statuses status)
{
    if (InvokeRequired)
    {
        Invoke(new Action<HttpHelper.Statuses>(UpdateStatus), status);
    }
    else
    {
        // Your code probably doesn't look like this;
        // it's just an example.
        statusLabel.Text = status.ToString();
    }
}
```

The reason you might see two successes followed by a failure is a bit beyond me; but I know that the `StatusLabel` control in particular can be a bit evasive when it comes to threading issues. I have seen code where it is updated directly from background threads (typically due to developer obliviousness) without any exception; it looks to me like you just got lucky twice and unlucky once.

Comment: Virtual -1.  NO!! It is Dispatcher.Invoke(). It is WPF/SilverLight not WPF.

Comment: @Aliostad: Good call; I think I see the problem, in that case. I will update (again)...

Comment: @Aliostad: Er... the OP was smart enough to figure it out. That makes my life easier ;)

Answer (score 0):

Does `Status` touch the UI? Because it seems like it.

I can only guess but I imagine `Status` changes something on UI which needs to be done through `Dispatcher.Invoke()`.

Answer (score -1):

if Status is a global variable you will get this exception becuase multiple threads are accessing and updating it at the same time. i suggest to use a lock around it